# Autonum wrong behaviour

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering, cleveref, autonum

I get the wrong behaviour with this code, using `autonum`. When one clicks on the hyperlink to the equation it jumps to the beginning of the page.

Minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks, breaklinks, citecolor=green, linkcolor=red,urlcolor=red, unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a-b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq} (a+b)^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1-10]
\eqref{eq}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user guide of the [autonum](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum) package explains, you need to load the `hyperref` package with the option `hypertexnames=false`. I would therefore change

```
\usepackage[colorlinks, breaklinks, citecolor=green, linkcolor=red,
   urlcolor=red, unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}
```

to

```
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=green, linkcolor=red,
     urlcolor=red, psdextra, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

Aside: Are you absolutely sure you need to set the option `psdextra`? (Note that I've already gone ahead and deleted the options `breaklinks` and `unicode`...)